# TikZ: Graph nodes containing math with curly braces

Tags: math-mode, tikz-trees, graphs

Is it possible to put math with commands that require curly braces inside graph nodes (and edges)? My attempt (see MNWE below, must be compiled with LuaLaTeX) does not seem the way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\graph [tree layout] {
    root -> "Child $C_\text{text}$"};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This causes an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikzgraphnodetext ->Child $C_\text 
                                    {text} $
l.14        $"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unrelated to `tikz` you need

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

to define `\text`

Also unrelated to `tikz` but it is much better to use the standard markup `C_{\text{text}}` rather rely on the weird artefact of the implementation of `\text` that allows the braces to  be omitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did not cross my mind to include `amsmath` in my `tikz` sandbox...

Comment: @FlorianL undefined command `\text` should have been a clue;-)